# Wordpress - Disable user notification on Email change

Tags: wordpress, notifications

I am looking for a snippet to completely disable the email notification sent out to users when an Admin changes their email in WordPress.

For context, it's this email:
[site name] Email Changed

Hi user name,

This notice confirms that your email address on [sitename] was changed to[ useremail].

If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator at
[admin email]

Answer (score 3):

Found this with a quick google

WP Docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/send_email_change_email/

```
<?php
// functions.php

add_filter( 'send_email_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Thank you!  that worked!  I swear i googled a ton w diff permutations and kept getting results related for "core update notification" and other email notifications not pertaining to email.

Comment: Nice, glad that worked for you!!!